# TextMate editor window live code return

Tags: textmate

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way in TextMate that I can send out the code I'm typing  on the fly to TextEdit.

Maybe some AppleScript or something, any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: One question: why? It honestly doesn't make much sense to me as to why someone would want to go from a more powerful editor to a less powerful one.

Comment: `Cmd+A, Cmd+C, Alt-Tab, Cmd+V`

Comment: @Mark I'm just experimenting with getting live data out of an editor. Sending it to TextEdit is just a simple thing I was asking to find out  how it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is seriously ugly, but works though. Requirements:

- Both TextMate and TextEdit need to be running
- Both need a document open in front

What it does is simply select all, copy, and paste over the TextEdit window.

```
tell application "TextMate"
  activate
  tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "a" using {command down}
    keystroke "c" using {command down}
  end tell
end tell

tell application "TextEdit"
  activate
  tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "a" using {command down}
    keystroke "v" using {command down}
  end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, it seems that the editor engine does not like the AppleScript for whatever reason.

Comment: @acreek Not a thing -- btw this is *not* the way you usually want to do stuff like this. If you're trying to learn AppleScript you should access the *text* objects of the TextMate window, rather than fiddling around with copy/pasting and emulating keypresses.